# Can't emulate ionic app after installing MediaCapture

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I have installed the ionic/cordova media capture package:

@awesome-cordova-plugins/media-capture
"cordova-plugin-media-capture"

But after this when i try to emulate the app it won't work, i just keep getting things like this:

[ng] Schema validation failed with the following errors:
[ng]   Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(allowedCommonJsDependencies).

The error means nothing to me, doesn't explain anything? Here are my files:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "displayName": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.10",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/media-capture": "^5.37.3",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.9.3",
    "@ionic/core": "^5.8.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.28",
    "angular-flatpickr": "^3.6.6",
    "angular-linky": "^1.2.2",
    "angular-password-strength-meter": "^3.0.1",
    "angularx-flatpickr": "^6.6.0",
    "angularx-social-login": "^3.5.7",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging": "^6.1.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.25.0",
    "emoji-js": "^3.6.0",
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.9",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ionicons": "^5.5.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "ng-socket-io": "^0.2.4",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "ngb-modal": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-emoji-picker": "0.0.2",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^10.1.1",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^3.3.5",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^9.1.0",
    "ngx-lightbox": "^2.5.1",
    "ngx-paypal": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.3.3",
    "ngx-ui-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.14.1",
    "ws": "^7.5.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1",
    "zxcvbn3": "^0.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.29",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.29",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.10",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.10",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "latest",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^9.1.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^6.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ecosystem:cordova"
  ],
  "author": "Apache Cordova Team",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-media-capture": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "www",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,

            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/ngx-lightbox/lightbox.css",
              "node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/core.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/normalize.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/structure.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/typography.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/display.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/padding.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/float-elements.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/text-alignment.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/text-transformation.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/flex-utils.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/theme/variables.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/core.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/normalize.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/structure.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/typography.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/display.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/padding.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/float-elements.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/text-alignment.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/text-transformation.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/flex-utils.css"
              },
              {
                "input": "src/theme/variables.css"
              }
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/emoji.js"
            ],

          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "50mb",
                  "maximumError": "100mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "60mb",
                  "maximumError": "100mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "staging": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ],
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "50mb",
                  "maximumError": "100mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "60mb",
                  "maximumError": "100mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*.svg",
                "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
                "output": "./svg"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/ngx-lightbox/lightbox.css",
              "node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/emoji.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "ionic-cordova-serve": {
          "builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-serve",
          "options": {
            "cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build",
            "devServerTarget": "app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "cordovaBuildTarget": "app:ionic-cordova-build:production",
              "devServerTarget": "app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "ionic-cordova-build": {
          "builder": "@ionic/angular-toolkit:cordova-build",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "app"
}
```

Comment: unsintall current version and Install wth whese commands:
1) `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture`
2) `npm install @ionic-native/media-capture`
and import it via: 
`import { MediaCapture, MediaFile, CaptureError, CaptureImageOptions, CaptureVideoOptions } from '@ionic-native/media-capture/ngx';
`

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib i already have done that